# Access child class object in base class overridden ToString method

Tags: c#, inheritance, this, tostring

I have multiple classes with all different structure. I wanted all my child classes `ToString` method to be overridden like this

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
}
```

So that I get a json serialized string for them.

Since I had multiple classes and I wanted exactly same thing, so I thought to have a base class where I would override the `ToString` method and it will work for all the sub classes, like this

```
public class ResponseBase
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }
}
```

And have child class like this

```
public class Response_1: ResponseBase
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

But when I try to do this,

```
Response_1 r = new Response_1();
r.Name = "Test";
var json = r.ToString(); // has empty json object "{}"
```

So the base class' overridden `ToString` method does get called because I get empty json string "{}" but it does not consider child object property while converting to json.

So basically `this` in this line, does not represent the child object of that time but the base object

```
return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
```

So the solution doesn't work.

Is there any way to achieve this? To have a `ToString` method overridden at one place for multiple classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the that generic version of `JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>` method is being called, where `T` is `ResponseBase`. You can fix this two ways:

Use another overload that lets you specify the type:

```
return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, this.GetType());
```

Cast the value to `object` so it calls the non-generic overload:

```
return JsonSerializer.Serialize((object)this);
```